# How to find special characters from Python Data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, special-characters

I need to find special characters from entire dataframe.

In below data frame some columns contains special characters, how to find the which columns contains special characters?

[image]

Want to display text for each columns if it contains special characters.

Comment: @Sqoshu OK, It would be great if you provide some code example?

Comment: Please take time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can setup an alphabet of valid characters, for example

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation
```

Which is

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

And just use

```
df.col.str.strip(alphabet).astype(bool).any()
```

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc', 'hello?'], 'col2': ['ÃÉG', 'Ç']})


    col1    col2
0   abc     ÃÉG
1   hello?  Ç
```

Then, with the above alphabet,

```
df.col1.str.strip(alphabet).astype(bool).any()
False
df.col2.str.strip(alphabet).astype(bool).any()
True
```

The statement *special characters* can be very tricky, because it depends on your interpretation. For example, you *might* or *might not* consider `#` to be a special character. Also, some languages (such as Portuguese) may have chars like `ã` and `é` but others (such as English) will not.

Comment: thanks, you saved me. How to display col values if it contains special characters.

Comment: I got it... df.col2.str.strip(alphabet)

Comment: how to remove it? Need to Strip special characters. ~df.col2.str.strip(alphabet) this not working

Answer (score 7):

To remove unwanted characters from dataframe columns, use regex:

```
def strip_character(dataCol):
    r = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z !@#$%&*_+-=|\:";<>,./()[\]{}\']')
    return r.sub('', dataCol)

df[resultCol] = df[dataCol].apply(strip_character)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Whitespaces also could be considered in some cases.

import string

unwanted = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.whitespace
print(unwanted)

# This helped me extract '10' from '10+ years'.

df.col = df.col.str.strip(unwanted)
```